Making Black Garlic
Black Garlic
I wrapped several bulb heads of garlic in aluminum foil and put them in my mini crockpot on low. After the 1st week, there was no moisture on the inside lid of my mini crockpot. I was under the impression that it takes 4 weeks to make black garlic. Today is day 13 and I unwrapped a few heads and found them to be black as can be but also hard as a rock. How would this have happened? Should I have pulled them out when the moisture 1st disappeared from under the lid in the 1st week?

When making black garlic like this, it depends on whether your appliance traps moisture by itself or not. If using a dehydrator or something similar, wrap the garlic heads tightly in plastic wrap, then a few layers of aluminium foil. If you're using a rice cooker or slow cooker that effectively seals against the outside, you can toss the garlic in unwrapped.
As you have seen, if the moisture evaporates, you dehydrate the garlic, making it hard and brittle in the process.
It would also be a good idea to check the temperature in your crockpot, as it should not exceed 60 °C.
For comparison, see this recipe from seriouseats.

Thank you. I will test this out again.
